# CGImage Display

Tags: swift, uiimage, cgimage

In swift I have a function where I want to display an image within an image context when the user touches the screen.  The code compiles correctly, but no image appears.  I'm confident that the error lies in this function because I'm not sure I fully understand how to display the image.  Am I going about producing the image in the right way?

```
func generateImage() -> UIImage {

    let centerX = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2
    let centerY = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) / 2
    var startPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    var endPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: centerX, y: centerY, width: 150, height: 150)
    let insideImage = UIImage(named: "at")
    let insideCGImage = insideImage?.CGImage

    // Generate the image
    // Begin an image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
    let imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    // Use CG to draw the image into the image context
    CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, imageRect, insideCGImage)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: Do you add the image to a view?

Comment: In the view controller I have a UIView that references the class, called ImageDrag.

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: ImageDrag!`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the return value of your function:

```
mainImage = generateImage()
```

Otherwise, the value isn't used anywhere and stays unused.

If your method is in an other class you have to create an instance and call the method:

```
var classInstance = YourClassWithTheFunction()
```

Then you can call the method like that:

```
mainImage = classInstance.generateImage()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.  The outlet variable, which is mainImage, from my controller can't access the generateImage function in the other class, which is ImageDrag.  When I try it, I get loads of errors.

Comment: You have to create an instance and call the method:  var classInstance = YourClassWithTheFunction()   Then you can call the method like that:  classInstance.generateImage()

Comment: The error I get is on the third line of this code: `@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: ImageDrag!
    var classInstance = ImageDrag(frame: CGRect())
    var mainImage = classInstance.ImageDrag()`  XCode brings up an error saying that  'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'classInstance'

Comment: I should add that I have an this as well in the ImageDrag class: `override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.contents = self.generateImage().CGImage
    }`